# Can a script determine its own process?

Tags: windows, powershell, process, windows-scripting

Say you have a single PowerShell script that can be started in multiple, simultaneous instances.  Is there any way for those scripts to identify which process each of them is running?

Basically, I'm looking for something like an imaginary:

```
$MyInvocation.processID
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$PID` automatic variable:

```
$ThisProcess = Get-Process -Id $PID
```

Comment: Ha!  Well, that's easy!  I didn't know about that one.  Thanks!